# FSL How to Track Users Locations?

Tags: geolocation

"When service resource tracking is enabled, the Field Service Lightning mobile app uploads the geolocation of app users to Salesforce at regular intervals."

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mfs_resource_tracking.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Okey but where these geolocation data? How can I access this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three fields on the ServiceResource Object; LastKnownLatitude and LastKnownLongitude, as well as LastKnownLocation with is Field Set of these two. There is also LastKnownLocationDate which is a date/time field that tells you when Last Known location is set.

You can visualize this from the Field Service app by clicking on the "Map" tab, next to the "Gantt" tab.  This shows you a visualization of all Service Appointments (Green Vans), Home Base Locations (Red Houses) and Last Known Locations (Green People).

Comment: Oh man! I've been looking for this answer all the day. Thank you very much.