# Field Service Lightning(FSL) Track field users location and being able to report on?

Tags: reporting, geolocation

Is there any way to report on the history of LastKnownLatitude and LastKnownLongitude on the Service Resource Object? An example use case is Service Resource "Bob" performs 3 Service appointments on a given day. Currently, the LastKnownLatitude and LastKnownLongitude fields will capture the location of the service resource, when the report is run. Is there a possible way to report on the history of Service Resource's Lat and Long at each service appointment level?

Here is a Q&A that can be used for better context:
[FSL How to Track Users Locations?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280243/fsl-how-to-track-users-locations/304365#304365)

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you have History Tracking enabled you have to create a Custom Report Type on Service Resource and Service Resource History. Then create a new report based on that type and you should be able to achieve your goal.